# How to remove the prefix generated in routes.rb for the params in the path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested-routes

Currently in my routes I have:

```
  # USER RESOURCES
  resources :users do
    resources :repositories
    patch 'change_password'
    get 'account_setting'
  end
```

Which generates this path for the `account_setting` action:

```
user_account_setting GET    /users/:user_id/account_setting(.:format)       users#account_setting
```

What I want is to have:

```
user_account_setting GET    /users/:id/account_setting(.:format)       users#account_setting
```

The two are essentially the same thing, but the first has a `user_` prefix for the `id` which rails adds because it is in users resource block.

**SIDE NOTE**

I know I can simply remove the `account_setting` action from the users resource block and write:

```
get 'users/:id/account_setting', to: 'users#account_setting'
```

But I don't want to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
 resources :users do
      member do
        get 'account_setting'
      end
    end
```

To add a member route, add a member block into the resource block.

For documentation, you can check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html